# ssmtp don't work and don't want to log

Tags: debian, sendmail, ssmtp

I've configured SSMTP to send mail, but the problem is that i can't send mail from my webserver and there is no logs in `/var/log`. Sometimes, i've got `Sender mismatch` in apache logs.

My config : Debian 11, and webserver into a Docker container.

This is my config of SSMTP :

```
hostname=domain.fr
root=no-reply@domain.fr
mailhub=mail.infomaniak.com:587
AuthUser=no-reply@domain.fr
AuthPass=PASS
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
Debug=YES
```

Into revaliases i've got :

```
www-data:no-reply@domain.fr:mail.infomaniak.com:587
root:no-reply@domain.fr:mail.infomaniak.com:587
```

**EDIT** : This is the part in my Dockerfile where I install and configure SSMTP :

```
&& apt -y install ssmtp mailutils \
&& echo "hostname=domain.fr" > /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
&& echo "root=no-reply@domain.fr" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
&& echo "mailhub=mail.infomaniak.com:587" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
&& echo "AuthUser=no-reply@domain.fr" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
&& echo "AuthPass=" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
&& echo "UseTLS=YES" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
&& echo "UseSTARTTLS=YES" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
&& echo "Debug=YES" >> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
&& echo "www-data:no-reply@domain.fr:mail.infomaniak.com:587" >> /etc/ssmtp/revaliases
```

For information, in CLI i can send emails while i'm on root account.

What could be my problem ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How did you configure the mail server inside the docker container?

Comment: I've edited my original post with the content of my Dockerfile :)

Comment: SSMTP logs through syslog but you probably don't have it inside the docker container.

Comment: @AlexD is there a possibility to have at least these logs ? What can i do ? I'm quite lost now 

Comment: You can mount `/dev/log` from the host into the container.

Comment: @AlexD Do you mean `/var/log` instead of `/dev/log` ? I don't have it in my container

Comment: I mean `/dev/log`. It is a socket used for `syslog` logging.

Comment: @AlexD I have mount `/dev/log` on my container (`--mount type=bind,src=/dev/log,dst=/dev/log`) but there is no more logs. For the error that I can have in apache is : `sendmail: 550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch`

Comment: You should look for logs in your host `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexD ! Logs are working, but the error is not very helpful...
```550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch
Can't open /var/www/dead.letter failing horribly!```
I don't know if the second line is a warning or a real error

Comment: The message means that your target mail server (`mailhub=mail.infomaniak.com:587`) rejected the message with `550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch`. Also, `SSMTP` tried to save the message in `/var/www/dead.letter` but failed, probably due to file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message `550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch` means that your target mail server (`mailhub=mail.infomaniak.com:587`) rejected a mail sent by `SSMTP`. Also, `SSMTP` tried to save the message in `/var/www/dead.letter` but failed, probably due to file permissions.

You need to check logs  `mail.infomaniak.com` to find out why it is rejecting your emails. You can also check `dead.letter` to ensure that it contains correct headers. You'll need to set the home directory for the user `SSMTP` running as to a directory where it has write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem after a lot of work !

If you have the same problem, to activate logs I mount `/dev/log` and `/var/www` to the container.

The server had a problem while writing into `/var/www/dead.letter` so I've created this file and put 777 permissions (for the test).

And finally, to solve `550 5.7.1 Sender mismatch` I asked to my email host to know what was the problem (I discovered that my email was blocked by their servers). And the problem (for Infomaniak.com) was that the sender and contact email was different than the domain used.

Thanks to every people that helped me !